# How to touch a file with JScript?

Tags: javascript, touch, wsh

Is there a way to touch a file (i.e. change its modification time) from a JScript? There is a `DateLastModified` property in `FileSystemObject` (ActiveXObject), but it's read-only.

Couldn't even find a clear "no, you can't" on this...

Answer (score 1):

The [`Shell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774094.aspx) object (`Shell.Application`) provides the read-write [`ModifyDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787825.aspx) property for files. Here's an example of how you can use it:

```
var oShell  = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var oFolder = oShell.NameSpace("C:\\MyFolder");
var oFile   = oFolder.ParseName("MyFile.txt");
oFile.ModifyDate = "11/11/2009 8:00:00 AM";
```

See also the *Hey, Scripting Guy!* article on the subject: [Using the Shell Object to Modify File Dates in VBScript](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.03.heyscriptingguy.aspx). (The sample code there is in VBScript, but it should help you get the idea.)